# How to check if ssh tunnel is active and connected?

Tags: sockets, go, ssh, chilkat

I want to check somehow if ssh tunnel is connected and I can use it with IMAP component.

Here I create the tunnel:

```
tunnel := chilkat.NewSocket()
tunnel.SshOpenTunnel("ip", 22)
tunnel.SshAuthenticatePw("username", "password")
```

And in some point I want to check it if it is still opened.

To simulate closed connection I turned off network cable and checked with the following methods:

```
imap.UseSshTunnel(tunnel)
```

and

```
tunnel.IsConnected()
```

But both returned true..

How can I check it ?

the following is HeartbeatMs property from chilkat

property: HeartbeatMs
 The number of milliseconds between periodic heartbeat callbacks for blocking
 socket operations (connect, accept, dns query, send, receive). Set this to 0 to
 disable heartbeat events. The default value is 1000 (i.e. 1 heartbeat callback
 per second).

Comment: SSH has no heartbeat - watch what happens when you use `ssh` from the terminal to connect to a remote machine and the remote times it out. It will sit there forever until it actually tries to communicate, at which point it will notice it's no longer connected. That's just the nature of the protocol.

Comment: @Adrian: ssh has keepalive in the protocol (separate from TCP), but no idea offhand if chilkat exposes the necessary pieces to use it.

Comment: @Adrian, I added to post info about heartbeat from chilkat. But then maybe I can send some data to tunnel to check it ? IS it good idea ?

Answer (score 0):

set the read timeout to a non zero

send a NOOP command to the imap server

check if the read succeeds, or if there is an error or timeout

Comment: yes I use it in some cases. But if even noop is failed - that may mean that it is not connected  to imap server. But tunnel may be still active and possible to be used. This is the question. I need to check exactly ssh tunnel, it's state, if I can use it